# DSG transmission fluid vs engine oil change

Tags: vw, maintenance, oil-change, transmission-fluid

Sorry for a rather rookie question. I am very new to vehicle maintenance, and trying to do my own oil change.

Recently I bought a used Volkswagen T5 Transporter 2.0 TDI DSG. And I've been looking at videos about oil change.

***My question is:*** Is the DSG transmission fluid the same as engine oil?

I see many people use 5W-40 oils, and they drain it from the bottom. And I've seen tutorials to change gearbox oil for manual transmissions. But I couldn't find any information about changing transmission fluid for DSG. I know generally engine oil is not transmission oil.

Sorry if it's a really stupid question. I would appreciate greatly as well if there are links to pictures - so I can kinda figure out how it looks like from the bottom of the car.

Bonus question: What is the engine filler cap for?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Have you checked what it says in the owner's manual?

Comment: funny but erm, my owner's manual is not in English, because I'm living in a foreign country. I can read some, but not very well.

Comment: The engine filler cap is there so you can put engine oil, of the correct grade, in when it needs topping up or changing.

Comment: If your Transporter is 2011 or later you can download the owner's manual from VW, you just need your VIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the DSG transmission fluid the same as engine oil?

No, it's a specific fluid (DSG's aren't conventional torque-converter automatics and you shouldn't use Automatic Transmission Fluid in them).

You can buy a kit for a DSG fluid change which should come with the requisite DSG oil (6 litres of the stuff IIRC) and filter. The DSG fluid should be changed every 40,000 miles.

Comment: ok! You're saying that changing DSG transmission fluid is different from changing engine oil on a T5. They both involve different set of fluids and filters? Thanks.

Comment: @jellene Yep.. the engine oil is changed more frequently - the interval and which exact oil to use will depend on whether your Transporter is on the "LongLife" service regimen or not. But they are two separate systems with two separate changes.

Answer (score 0):

Gearbox fluid and engine oil are different things. If you are a beginner you should probably think twice about changing your gearbox oil, especially since you probably don't need to - it's something with a long life.

The filler cap is removed to let you fill the engine oil reservoir, when it's in place it prevents the engine oil from being contaminated and keep it from splashing out of the engine when it's running - which it will do if you forget to put it on!

If you want to get started on maintenance then I recommend you get a workshop manual specific for the car. Haynes makes them, you might find a VW one online, they are worth every penny as they take the guesswork out of the process. There are some great youtube videos out there covering how to do specific tasks, but the manuals tell you what those specific tasks are. Make sure you have all the tools you may need and the time and place to do the work. Also, **safety!** Cars weigh tons, so make sure you have the right jacks,  stands and wheel chocks available.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look to buy the manual from somewhere online and ship it here.

Comment: Where is here @jellene?

Comment: here is finland.

Comment: You may be able to get an English language manual from Amazon UK or Ebay, it's worth having a look.